# How do I create a javascript promise which resolves to a thenable?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm working with the [faye browser client](http://faye.jcoglan.com/browser.html) using promises, and I have a function that creates a faye client after doing something asynchronous, like so:

```
function fayeClient() {
  return doSomethingAsychronous().then(function() {
    var faye_client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost/faye');
    return faye_client;
  });
}
```

and I want to use it like so:

```
fayeClient().then(function(faye_client) {
  // do something with faye_client
});
```

The problem is, `faye_client` is also a *thenable*, which means that the promise returned by `fayeClient` resolves to the value that `faye_client` 'resolves' to.
However, I want the promise to resolve directly to `faye_client`.

I can't even manually wrap the value in a promise using `Promise.resolve(faye_client);`, since the same [promise resolution procedure](http://promisesaplus.com/) is used.

I think this could indicate a misuse of thenables on faye's part, since `faye_client` does not represent a value which is not yet known.

Is there any way to make a promise which resolves to a value which is also a thenable?

Comment: Excellent question.  I'm a bit confused by one phrase though: what do you mean by "a misuse of promises on faye's behalf"?  Do you mean "a misuse of promises on faye's part", i.e. "a misuse of promises by faye"? (In which case, how could it be that faye misusing promises? If I understand correctly, faye doesn't use promises at all; it just happens to have a "then" method.)  Or do you mean "promises are misbehaving on faye's behalf"?  Or do you mean "I'm misusing promises on faye's behalf"?

Comment: Yes, I meant "a misuse of promises on faye's part", but that was slightly inaccurate, so I should have said "a misuse of thenables on faye's part".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of returning `faye_client` directly wrap it in an object. It's ugly but it's kind of your only choice with A+ promises:

```
return {client: faye_client}; // no longer a thenable
```

Some alternative promise implementation expose a .then or .chain that doesn't recursively assimilate but honestly I'd avoid those.

Comment: I ended up creating an adaptor object for the faye client. Now I can use exactly the api I want throughout my code.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is what I meant here. You can not use a `then`able as a return value directly, you must wrap it. Sorry for the short answer by the way I was on my phone and didn't want to leave you hanging.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the `new Promise` constructor to resolve the promise?

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(faye_client);
});
```

Comment: Although, maybe `resolve` suffers from the same "thenable" logic?

Comment: That depends on the used library, but most libs would assimilate thenables in `resolve`. However, I'm currently writing one that can be `fulfill`ed without assimilation.

Comment: @Bergi it's in the specification. There are [alternative libraries that don't follow the spec](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-promises) but honestly they're unpopular since they're generally harder to use and don't expose as good as an API. Also related - http://esdiscuss.org/topic/promise-cast-and-promise-resolve

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Only `then` is spec'd as of now, the Promise constructors are still proposals. Notice that the lib you've linked is actually a Lazyness wrapper, it's not even asynchronous - not we what we understand of promises. I mean something like [this (disclaimer: not yet finished)](https://github.com/bergus/F/blob/master/Promise.js), which will get A+compliant eventually

Comment: @Bergi looks nice :) Good luck with it. As for promise constructors - they're a proposal for A+ but they're specced for ES6 promises.